# Calling a service function after stingify file. Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to call a function from a service with the string resulting from a stringify operation.
But when i try to call it "this.xmlservice.parsexml" it says that this function is not available for FileReader. I dont know when im calling the FileReader class.

HTML:

```
<input type="file" id="upload" style="display:none" (change)="handleMTPInput($event.target.files)">
```

JS:

```
constructor(private fileService: fileService, private xmlservice: XMLservice, private _http: HttpClient, private libservice: libraryService) { }

handleMTPInput(files: FileList) {
if (files.length === 0) {
  console.log('No file is selected');
  return;      
}
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function (event) {
  this.xmlservice.parsexml(event.target.result[0]);
};
reader.readAsText(files[0]);  
}
```

Comment: check the context of your 'this', probably it refers to instance of FileReader , instead of instance of your class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an arrow function instead so that your `this` context is the class in your JS code, like so:

```
constructor(private fileService: fileService, private xmlservice: XMLservice, private _http: HttpClient, private libservice: libraryService) { }

handleMTPInput(files: FileList) {
if (files.length === 0) {
  console.log('No file is selected');
  return;      
}
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = (event) => this.xmlservice.parsexml(event.target.result[0]);

reader.readAsText(files[0]);  
}
```